# Trigger execution warnings with Logic App Standard on Azure Function Runtime

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-functions-runtime, azure-triggers

I've got a Logic App (Standard) running on an Azure Function runtime, and I've noticed I'm getting spammed with warnings for my O365 When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2) trigger.

```
Trigger is meant to execute on cluster type 'Classic'. However, it is executing on cluster 'NotSpecified'
```

Just Created a Logic App (Standard) and created an O365 trigger on a shared mailbox v2 trigger.
Allowed the trigger to fire

Log Stream/AppInsights will show the warning about trigger execution: `Trigger is meant to execute on cluster type 'Classic'. However, it is executing on cluster 'NotSpecified'`

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for the error that is mentioned above. One way to solve this problem is by **reconfiguring** the O365 Logic App Connection and try again.

Usually it happens when there is a version mismatch of the library reference or older version of the component referenced in logic app. If still the error persist, error handling need to be implemented properly in logic apps to get detailed error. App Insight will give proper error log and provide us the error logs if issue still persist.

Please check this [Handle errors and exceptions in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling) documentation from Microsoft for more information.